# Best/Fastest way to add a line to the start of a txt file

Tags: linux, performance, shell

I need to re applying the header row to a data file after the split. The original file is multiple gigs of a txt file. After the split command adding a header appears to be taking most of the time. I've tried this two ways:

```
    for i in file_split_*; do
        echo "Adding header to $i"
        echo -e "$HEADER\n$(cat $i)" > $i
```

and

```
    for i in file_split_*; do
        echo "Adding header to $i"
        sed -i "1i\\$HEADER" file_split_*
```

At a small scale test 100,000 rows split into files of 10,000 rows (10,001 after header is added) I found that echo was faster (6s for sed vs 2.6s for echo). Is there another/ faster way to add a header row?

Comment: Wait, are you running sed multiple times for each file?

Comment: sed should be run one time on each file to insert the header only. There are multiple files after a 'split' command is run earlier in script. This loop runs sed on file_split_00, then on file_split_01, then 02... until all new smaller files have the same header.

Comment: The options are: Read the entire file into memory, truncate the original file on disk to 0 bytes, write the header and saved contents to it, or b) write the header and contents of file to a new temporary file and rename it to the original. Your first example does the first, your second example does the second. If your files are that big, the second one likely becomes the only feasible approach.

Comment: @RunThor: Are you sure? You don't show what `$1` contains, but you seem to be running sed in a loop, but the header doesn't change in the loop, so you can just run sed once an all the files.

Comment: I think you meant `sed -i "1i\\$HEADER" "$i"` in the second block?

Comment: Which can be shortened to just `sed -i "1i\\$HEADER" file_split_*`.

Comment: sorry the original post, second block had the original script with uses $1 to accept a file name, so post splut it was $1_split_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@choroba and @Shawn
Thank you both for pointing out a mistake in the loop.

As posted the loop was adding the header multiple times to all files. I assumed sed would be faster but couldn't figure out how echo was faster, this explains it.

```
    for i in file_split_*; do
       echo "Adding header to $i"
       sed -i "1i\\$HEADER" file_split_*   <for ever loop write to all files
```

To fix the loop I need $i

```
    for i in $1_split_*; do
       echo "Adding header to $i"
       sed -i "1i\\$HEADER" "$i"   <for every look write to one file
```

Because of what was happening in the first block I may not need to loop at all.